# I'm getting an ERROR of Infinite loop while comparing 2 ArrayList one from server and the another from local Db

Tags: android, list, loops, server

I'm trying to compare the ArrayList values between the server ArrayList and local DB ArrayList. Where I compare the ID of each ArrayList object from Server and local DB ArrayList and store if its new data to the DB ArrayList.

Below is my Code.

```
if(!listServer.isEmpty()){
    for(Model server:listServer){
         for(Model Db:listDb){
             while(!listServer.get( i ).getid().equals(listDb.get(i).getid() )){
                  storeIntoDb.add( listServer.get( i ) );
             }
         }
    }
}
```

I get an infinite loop in the new list which needed to store into local DB. Actually what I want is to compare if I have a new data in the server then store it into local DB.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Is every object is coming in the same order from the server and without any new record only data will be change?

Comment: There will be new record from the server. So i needed compare the data between server and DB if not same means is new data , then  when new record then store into localDB.

Comment: If you have new record from server then why you are comparing the object by there poistion.

Comment: how big are both lists?

Comment: every time the listServer will be 5 until all data is call. Then listDB will getting more and more if there is new data in the server.

Comment: so you want to find out where both list differ (calculate the difference between two lists), right?

Comment: yup,then save into local DB...

Comment: then see `android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
for(Model server:listServer){
   boolean inDb = false;
   for(Model db:listDb){
     if(server.getId().equals(db.getId()) {
        inDb = true;
        break;
     }
   }
   if(!inDb) {
       storeIntoDb.add(server);
   }
}
```

This will do what you want to do, But this approach will lead to performance issues after your database grows.

Comment: Hi , i getting the same new value and loop 5 times for each. I think is because the compare between server and data  is one on one not one to many?  I think then only way can solve the problem is. The 1st data from server will loop all the Db data then only store into DB.

Comment: each server item is compared with each item in db (except if there is match).

Comment: Hi, i found the problem is the listServer appear duplicate value. Your method is work and problem solve.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if(!listServer.isEmpty()){
for(Model server:listServer){
     for(Model db:listDb){
         if(!server.getid().equals(db.getid() )){
              toreIntoDb.add( server );
              }
            }
          }
       }
```

Comment: Hi , the result is the same , getting the infinite looping again.